# mysql query with if else statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have following fields in my **ad_table** table:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|ADVT_ID | RELATIVE_ID | AD_TYPE | AD_LOCATION | AD_IMAGE  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|1       | 2            |  FP    | H           | test1.jpg |
|2       | 0            |  FP    | H           | test2.jpg |
|3       | 0            |  TB    | H           | test3.jpg |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to use two if statements in mysql query.
I want to retrieve data from table using mysql query in this format:

**FIRST IF STATEMENT :**

> if (AD_TYPE = 'FP' && AD_LOCATION = 'H') 
>     
> then select all data from
>     
> table where RELATIVE_ID !=0

**SECOND IF STATEMENT :**

> if(AD_TYPE != 'FP' && AD_LOCATION != 'H') 
>     
> then select all data from 
>  table where RELATIVE_ID =0

So how to do that in mysql query?

Comment: Why do this in mysql? Use php to process which query you will call. You should always limit the number of calls to the MYSQL servers and offload as much processing on the application (php) side. Of course, you might not be able to do that... but this is the ideal setup.

Comment: Are you talking about the [`IF` flow control statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html) or the [`IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)? The first one is only available in procedures and functions and you don't mention you're writing one. The function, of course, is not a flow control structure. Also, what does the PHP tag have to do with your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM ad_table
WHERE (AD_TYPE = 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION = 'H' AND RELATIVE_ID !=0)
   OR (AD_TYPE != 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION != 'H' AND RELATIVE_ID =0)
```

Comment: i want to do something like that if(AD_TYPE = 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION = 'H') then select all data where RELATIVE_ID !=0                       if(AD_TYPE != 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION != 'H') then select all data where RELATIVE_ID =0

Comment: "if(AD_TYPE = 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION = 'H')", but for which line ? These values are not constant over your table.

Comment: i want to use two if statements in mysql query

Comment: First IF :if(AD_TYPE = 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION = 'H') then select all data where RELATIVE_ID !=0 SECOND IF :if(AD_TYPE != 'FP' AND AD_LOCATION != 'H') then select all data where RELATIVE_ID =0

Comment: You don't understand.

Comment: AD_TYPE and AD_LOCATION values change at each line, right ?

Comment: So the value inside your IF changes every line, right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51575/discussion-between-m-massias-and-s4suryapal)